# ionic : File C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: reactjs, ionic-native

ionic : File C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ionic --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 72):

Run the following command in same terminal

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: thanks for this answer @kunal shaktawat , this should be marked as Answer of this question.

Comment: thanks!  This answer solves the issue. Please author, mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the file `ionic.ps1` from its location "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1"

Answer (score 0):

if you using **yarn**

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```